# How to clean up my code in Android Studio?

Tags: android, build

I'm fairly new to Android programming but have experience with other areas. I used to use a program called AutoIT for programming scripts used in Windows.  When building the project there was an option that would clean up my code.

Giving each line proper indents, removing blank lines and I even think here as an option that would remove unused variables as well.  I believe this was a plug in or add-on script that did this during build. Does Android Studio have something similar?

Comment: `preferences -> code style`, it is probably a good start

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I want to answer just this image, but I can't. There has to be at least 30 characters.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the help, this is the closest answer I could find as well but does not remove blank lines or unused variables.

Comment: You will have to remove the unused variables by yourself. Reformat code does duplicate blink lines removing but it depends on Code Style settings.

Comment: That's what I needed, someone commented in the original post with preferences-->codestyle I figured that as a "wise comment".  I see it now, this is great.. THANKS